# How to declare this kind of Structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to declare and insert elements in this type of structure which is required by the web service. So the input of my service like this:

```
data["A"]["12"]="word" (data)["String"]["String"]=(String)
```

i dont know if this called (HashList or MapList)
I think it's not a Multi dimensional array becore is not indexed by 0,1....n
How can i declare this type of structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just an object:

```
var data = {
    A: {
        '12': 'word'
    }
}
```

Properties of JavaScript objects can be accessed or set using a bracket notation, just as in your example.

[Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: you have a typo. should be `data = {`

Comment: @t.niese: 10x, I fixed it.

Comment: Thinks a lot for declaration , how can i fill it with data ? if it is an example it would be great ?